# CherryPy: what is the difference between `error_page.default` vs. `error_page.404` config settings?

Tags: python, cherrypy

Let's say I want to display my own 404 & 500 pages, I've found 2 possibilities so far:

1: Using `cherrypy.config.update`

```py
def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    return ('Error 404 Page not found')

def error_page_500(status, message, traceback, version):
    return ('Error:')

cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.404': error_page_404, 'error_page.500': error_page_500})
```

2. Using `_cp_config`:

```py
from cherrypy import _cperror

def handle_error():
    cherrypy.response.status = 500
    cherrypy.log("handle_error() called. Alarm!", "WEBAPP")
    cherrypy.response.body = ['Sorry, an error occured. The admin has been notified']
    error = _cperror.format_exc()

def error_page(status, message, traceback, version):
    cherrypy.log("error_page() called. Probably not very important.", "WEBAPP")
    return "Sorry, an error occured."

class Root: 
     _cp_config = { 
         'error_page.default': error_page, 
         'request.error_response': handle_error 
     }
```

but is there a difference or a suggestion which is preferable to use?

Comment: `error_page.default` is a catch-all, it's used if the error code doesn't have its own handler.

Comment: Honestly, I don't quite understand the motivation of this question.

Comment: @webKnjaZ , I have 2 options and they seem to do something similar - my motivation is understand what the fundamental difference is and what the standard way to handle it is. This is a learning and asking platform after all, so even though it might be a silly question - I think it serves a purpose.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653890/595220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.error_response` allows you to set a handler for processing of some unexpected errors, like your own exceptions raised from HTTP handlers.
The callable that you'll set for this option will receive no arguments at all and you'll have to inspect [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) for the details, to find out what happened.
You'll also **have to** set `cherrypy.response.status` and `cherrypy.response.body` by yourself, explicitly in your error handler.

If you want to modify the error response for HTTP error codes (when instances of `cherrypy.HTTPError` are raised, like `raise cherrypy.NotFound`), you can use `error_page.default` (catch-all) or `error_page.404` (error-specific) for handling those errors.
`error_page` options support both file path and callable values. In case of using a file path, the HTML template file can use the following substitution patterns: `%(status)s`, `%(message)s`, `%(traceback)s`, and `%(version)s`.
If you opt-in to using a function, it'll receive those as arguments (`callback(status, message, traceback, version)`). The return value of this callable is then used HTTP response payload.

As you can see, these approaches have different implications and different levels of flexibility and usability. Choose whatever works for you. Internally, the default `request.error_response` uses `error_page` settings to figure out what to return. So if you redefine `request.error_response`, it'll not use `error_page.*` settings unless you explicitly make it do so.

See [the docstring with some explanation here](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/9ac7b91/cherrypy/_cperror.py#L51-L118).