# Can I make CherryPy return errors in JSON format?

Tags: cherrypy

Is it possible to configure my CherryPy API script to always reply in JSON format?

It's currently returning errors in a HTML page.

Example for what I want a reply to look like:

```
{
    "error": "404",
    "title": "page not found",
    "message": "blah blah blah the page does not exist. you suck",
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Use `error_page` tool or `request.error_response` to modify the default behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653890/595220. Once you learn the details, please don't forget to write a detailed answer to this for anybody else who'll be searching for this in the future. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Here is a simple implementation

```
def jsonify_error(status, message, traceback, version):
    response = cherrypy.response
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return json.dumps({'status': 'Failure', 'status_details': {
        'message': status,
        'description': message
    }})
```

You need to add this tool in the config before starting the `cherrypy` server

```
'error_page.default': jsonify_error
```